# Objects in memory python

Tags: python, pandas

What is the command to know objects in memory ?

My problem is as below :

1) Before the execution of a function, I have 1.71 Go of full memory

2) After execution of a function which read a csv file, memory is 1.98 Go

3) After have droped the variable created by the function, my memory is 1.92 Go.

==> I loss 0.21 Go by don't know why !!!

```
def import():
    df1 = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx') 
    return df1

aa = import()
del aa
```

Comment: the memory will not necessarily be freed immediately due to garbage collection, what can help but is not 100% is to use the `gc` module, so if you added `import gc` and then called `gc.collect()` after you call `del aa` then you may see some recovery in the memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import gc
gc.get_objects()  # returns a list of objects tracked by CPython's garbage collector
```

I suggest you read the following: http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/GetAllObjects and its follow-up http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/GetAllObjectsII .